# Let $f$ be holomorphic in $B_r(0)$ with $r>1$. Prove that:

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in $B_r(0)$ with $r>1$. Prove that:

\begin{center}
    $$ \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int f(e^{it})\cos^2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}t \right)dt=f(0)+\dfrac{1}{2} f'(0)$$

This is on the chapter The development of holomorphic functions into power series, but I am not shore if I have to use the Lemma on developability. I dont really know what to do. I would really appreciate a Hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think $f(e^{i}t)$ should be $f(e^{it})$. Also the integral must be over $(-\pi, \pi)$ (or any interval of length $2\pi$). The integral over the whole real line need not exist.

If you show that the equation holds when $f(z)=z^{n}$ then you can show that it holds in general since the power series of $f$ converges uniformly on the unit circle. For $f(z)=z^{n}$ use the fact that $\cos^{2} (\frac t 2)=\frac 1  2(1+\cos t)=\frac 1  4(2+e^{it}+e^{-it})$. Now you are left with evaluation of some simple integrals. I will let you finish the proof.